# Cancancan nested resources Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I got a controller named `FileRecord`, it can be accessed from two different paths

From a User with Role Admin

```
/customers/:customer_id/record_types/:record_type_id/file_records
```

From a Common User

```
record_types/:record_type_id/file_records
```

Is there a way to block access to admin to the route of the common user and viceversa?

Thanks

Comment: define an ability that forbids the certain user from the actions you don't wan't them to view, for example if a user is the only one able to view his record files... then add this to his ability ex `can :manage FileRecord, owner_id: user.id` assuming that your `FileRecord` model has a `owner_id` filed that maps to the owner of the file